# Как удалить записи из реестра?

Tags: visual-c++, реестр

Написала программу на си++. Запускается, соответственно, с .exe-файла. Понятно, что программа оставляет в реестре "следы".

Вопрос заключается в следующем: как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии программы регистрационные записи именно об этой программе удалялись из реестра?

То есть, как я понимаю, нужно сначала каким-то образом определить, какие записи она сдела, и потом их удалить. Извините, в работе с реестром СОВСЕМ новичок, буду признательна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, это поможет:
Writing a self destructing exe file
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4027/Writing-a-self-destructing-exe-file
или здесь похожая проблема
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457040/how-to-write-a-program-in-c-such-that-it-will-delete-itself-after-execution

Answer (score 1):

Мне вот, например, непонятно, с чего она вдруг "оставляет в реестре следы". Если вы сами её заставляете писать где-то следы, вы должны знать, где. Если вы пользуетесь сторонними пакетами, в которых вам лень разбираться, но они пишут в реестр, воспользуйтесь утилитами вроде RegMon, который в реальном времени отследит все обращения вашей программы к реестру.